# Make a an image move from one location to another random location every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to make a mini-game where when one image intersects with another image they would score a point. This is everything I have. I am trying to make an image (aka snitch) move to a random location every time picplayer intercepts with snitch. Can someone also help me fix my code as my player teleports randomly for some reason. Thank you

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x, y;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //enable the timer when the start button is clicked
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create a random x and y coordinate
            Random r = new Random();
            x = r.Next(1, 500);
            y = r.Next(1, 500);
           
            //Creates the picturebox on your form
            PictureBox villain = new PictureBox();
            villain.Location = new Point(x, y);
            villain.Height = 150;
            villain.Width = 150;
            villain.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            villain.Image = Properties.Resources.snitch;
            this.Controls.Add(villain);
          
            if (picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(villain.Bounds))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You won");
                villain.Dispose();

            }

        }   

        //Moves harry potter according to the keys pressed
        private void textBox1_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                y -= 10;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                y += 10;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                x -= 10;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                x += 10;
            }
            picPlayer.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Comment: You're using the same x and y variables for your villian and your player.

Comment: I tried this picPlayer.Location = new Point(10, 10); but it kept bringing me to that coordinate again and again.

Comment: Of course, that will keep moving the player to 10, 10. What you need is a player_x and player_y, and a villian_x and villian_y.

Comment: In addition to comments about x and y usage, why create a new villain image each time? Also: `villain.Height = -->2150<--;` ??????????

Comment: @Loocid What you mean by player_x and player_y, and a villian_x and villian_y. How would I do that?

Comment: @OlivierRogier how to I not create a new image each time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, there's no need to create new PictureBox for your villain each time.  Below I've moved your Random instance and the villain PictureBox out to Form level (the same place as you existing x and y variables).  Next we setup the villain in the `Load()` event as these properties don't change.  Finally, we use different variables for the random location of the villain so that the player doesn't get changed:

```
int x, y;
Random r = new Random();
PictureBox villain = new PictureBox();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    villain.Height = 150;
    villain.Width = 150;
    villain.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    villain.Image = Properties.Resources.snitch;
    this.Controls.Add(villain);
    villain.Hide();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //enable the timer when the start button is clicked
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a random x and y coordinate
    int villX = r.Next(1, 500);
    int villY = r.Next(1, 500);         
    villain.Location = new Point(villX, villY);
    villain.Show();
    
    if (picPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(villain.Bounds))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You won");
        villain.Hide();
    }
}
```